# Discordjs: Specifying channel for an interaction.reply

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using Discordjs v13. I have created a slash command and I am able to "print" a message using

```
await interaction.reply(messageObj);
```

I need to send the reply to a different channel where the command was triggered, is this possible?

Something like:

```
interaction.setChannel(channelId).reply(...)
```

OR

```
interaction.reply({
    channel: ....
    ....
    })
```

Comment: const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'your id') 
This one?

Comment: @httpanand with that line you get a channel by id. I need to specify a channel where the interaction.reply response should be shown

Comment: You need to enter command in one channel and the api should return in another channel?

Comment: Interactions are meant to be replied to in the same channel - it would be confusing to the user, and the programmer if it wasn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not possible. The Discord API does not allow to specify the channel where the app interaction should be replied in: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#responding-to-an-interaction

However if you are concerned with the reply being shown to everyone, you can make the reply ephemeral. If you want to log interactions, you can reply to the interaction then send another message using the solution provided in the comments of your question.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually possible in discordjs v14 and may be in v13 as well. Carl-bot does it with suggestions.but its not an actual reply
use

```
interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send('message')
```

this will send a message in a the select channel you may still want to

```
interaction.reply({Content:'replied in #channel' [embed], ephemeral: true })
```

so the user knows the reply was redirected . ephemeral: true makes the replay only visible to the user that evoked the interaction.
and if you need the message id for the new message use

```
const msg = await interaction.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').send('message');
```

to send the message and you can do something like `const messageid = msg.id`